# Django signal when model instance with custom field is deleted?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got a custom model field in my Django app:

```py
secret = VaultField(max_length=200)
```

This takes the value passed and saves it to HashiCorp Vault and stores the path to it in the database, and retrieves it from Vault when accessing.

That's all good, I can use this on many models.

But now when I delete an instance of a model it doesn't delete it from Vault.

I could add a post delete signal on all models that have the `VaultField` field, but that seems like a lot of duplicate work.

Is there anything to add in the `class VaultField(CharField):` class?

Or maybe a post delete signal just on a field being deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the delete() method of Models which have the VaultField

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    secret = VaultField(max_length=200)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Put your custom delete code here
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can also make the delete method in a Abstract Model which can be inherited from in your other models, if you dont want to repeat the delete method override in all your Models.

```
class Base(models.Model):
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Or you could even write it in a mixin class maybe